# Using two different structures in one Firebase database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a project where I need two different types of non-related datastructures in my Java Android app. One being users, the other being types of food.

Users are set up like this:

users

- userid

  - name
  - age
  - gender
  - weight
  - height

But, I also need one that looks like this, which must be searchable:

foods

- name

  - carbohydrate
  - fat
  - protein

Is it possible to user the same database (preferrable Firebase, as I'm already using that), or do I need to add another database to the app I'm making?

**Edit:** I ended up exporting the JSON, rewriting it according to the good answers given here, and then importing it again. It works flawlessly. Thanks for your answers!

```
{
  "foods" : {
      "name" : {
        "carbohydrates" : "5",
        "fats" : "5",
        "proteins" : "5"
    }
  },    
  "users" : {
    "FjtMNTcDrOP2wcaPAa0E0Cc1jRz2" : {
      "activity" : "Moderate Exercise (3–5 days/week)",
      "age" : "40",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "height" : "180",
      "name" : "Flex",
      "weight" : "86"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to model multiple entity types (such as your `users` and `foods`) in the Firebase Realtime Database. While it doesn't have the concept of a table, it's a hierarchy of JSON values and you can model any structure you want in that.

For example, you could express you data model with this JSON:

```
{
  "users": {
    "userid": {
      "name": "value", 
      "age": 42,
      "gender: "value", 
      "weight": 190,
      "height": 172
    }
  },
  "foods": {
    "name": {
      "carbohydrate": 42
      "fat": 11,
      "protein": 8
    }
  }
}
```

In relational terms, the above model defines two "tables": `users` and `foods`. In Android code you can define separate references to each of these with:

```
DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersReference = rootReference.getChild("users");
DatabaseReference foodsReference = rootReference.getChild("foods");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the same Firebase Realtime Database to store that data.

The RTDB can be simplified down to being just a JSON tree. So for your desired implementation, you would have two keys at the root of your database (such as "users" and "foods").

```
{
  "users": {
    "userid1": {
      "name": "somestring",
      "age": "somenum",
      "gender": "somestring",
      "height": "somenum",
      "weight": "somenum",
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  "foods": {
    "food1": {
      "name": "somename",
      "carbs": "somenum",
      "fat": "somepercent",
      "protein": "somepercent",
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

You can also add or remove more root keys as you wish and your project takes shape.

### However,

As [@Tamir Abutbul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8274756/tamir-abutbul) suggests in their answer, I would use Cloud Firestore for this project over the RTDB.

The reason for this is that based on your data, you are likely going to need to filter results by a number of different values at a time in the future. Cloud Firestore supports these types of queries natively ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)) whereas you'd need to write a custom solution for the RTDB.

[Getting Started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Comment: Thank you. I'm sticking to Firebase as this is simply a proof of concept app. I'll keep your answer in mind in case I move forward with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase with [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).

Create "users" collections with your wanted data structure and another collection called "foods" with its own data structure.

The next step is just to decide when to use any one of those collections(according to your app logic).